# Is it safe to use t-sql REPLACE() in joins?

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, replace

I have two tables I need to join in SELECT statement, but in one of them username is just plain username and in the other one there is domain\ prefix.

Is it safe to just REPLACE domain\ with empty string, so they will match?
I am thinking this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
JOIN table2 on REPLACE(table1.username, 'domain\', '') = table2.username
```

I tested this and it looks like it works, but I'd like to avoid changing anything in db of course..

Comment: `REPLACE()` has 3 arguments. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) Why don't you just give your query a try and see what happens?

Comment: You are right, I missed string I am trying to replace, it's now edited. I did achieve what I wanted using this function, but I wanted to make sure it's safe to use. I don't want to replace anything in the tables themself.

Comment: What if you have a user from another domain in `table1`?

Comment: A select statement can not change the data in the db, so yes, it's safe. Will it produce the correct results? well, that's something we can't answer for you without sample data and expected results.

Comment: I ran it and it looks good for me. All users have the same domain so there is no risk of missing any because of that. I will probably use other type of join, to avoid problems in situation where there is no user in 1st table. Thank you for clarification.

Comment: What did you learn when you read the documentation? Read that before you ask a question.